# Update a pipeline in Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am studying for the Data Engineer exam and, during my exercises, I have found this question:

*You are operating a streaming Cloud Dataflow pipeline. Your engineers have a new version of the pipeline with a different windowing algorithm and triggering strategy. You want to update the running pipeline with the new version. You want to ensure that no data is lost during the update. What should you do?*

- A. Update the Cloud Dataflow pipeline inflight by passing the
  --update option with the --jobName set to the existing job name .
- B. Update the Cloud Dataflow pipeline inflight by passing the --update
  option with the --jobName set to a new unique job name .
- C. Stop the
  Cloud Dataflow pipeline with the Cancel option. Create a new Cloud
  Dataflow job with the updated code .
- D. Stop the Cloud Dataflow
  pipeline with the Drain option. Create a new Cloud Dataflow job with
  the updated code.

In the official documentation: "*We recommend that you attempt only smaller changes to your pipeline's windowing, such as changing the duration of fixed- or sliding-time windows. Making major changes to windowing or triggers, like changing the windowing algorithm, might have unpredictable results on your pipeline output.*".

Therefore, I don't know if the correct answer is A or D. I think that A is more suitable when we don't want to lose data.

Answer (score 1):

The google documentation did mention that if the windowing or triggering algorithm changes, you might have unpredictable results. This question did mention change in windowing and triggering algorithm. Safe bet is D.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is A because the question has a preconditions that no data is lost during the update. From the official documentation on [updates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/updating-a-pipeline#UpdateMechanics):

> The replacement job preserves any intermediate state data from the prior job, as well as any buffered data records or metadata currently "in-flight" from the prior job. For example, some records in your pipeline might be buffered while waiting for a window to resolve.

This means that the data will be temporarily saved (i.e. buffered) until the new pipeline is running with the state from the old job. Once the new pipeline is running, the buffered data will be sent to the new job.

In addition, the documentation states the the updated job's name [must match the old job](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/updating-a-pipeline#specifying_your_replacement_job_name), therefore it's not B.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with A. the new pipeline is incompatible with the prior one because the window/trigger has changed. Isn't it safer to create a new pipeline while avoiding conflicts?